# Why does this page look like crap in IE8 but load fine in Firefox and Chrome?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

Note that the home page looks awful in IE8:

http://www.amateurgourmet.com/

...but individual posts look fine, with the same style sheet:

http://www.amateurgourmet.com/2013/01/brittany-cake-aux-pruneaux.html

Here's what it looks like in IE8 (and possibly IE9):
[image]

Why is that? I've tried validating the code and while there are lots of warnings (this is some awful code I've inherited, and lots of 3rd party plugins), I don't see anything obvious.

Everything looks great in Firefox, Chrome, Safari.

Comment: Can you post some screenshots? Not everyone has IE8 installed.

Comment: Without context this question will be useless in the future. Please include relevant code and ideally a reduced test case of what issues you're having.

Comment: FWIW, IE9 truncates the page for me. (Can just barely see the top of the page heading below the nav menu).

Comment: That's the issue-- truncated page. Some crazy IE issue. I'll add a screen shot.

Comment: Why on earth does almost every `div#id` have a `height:1%` specified? Just going through the debugger and disabling that style sheet (#content, #main, #center, #right) makes the page tolerable.

Comment: I was actually just looking at that myself and I Googled the 1% stuff... it's some kind of old IE7 hack (called the "Holly hack"). (Like I said, I just inherited this code, and there's a lot of weird stuff going on.) That's definitely going on the list to clean up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least one of the issues is the comment you have before the DOCTYPE declaration. That throws all version of IE into quirks mode. Remove that and you should be golden.

Also, IE's not truncating the page (as you can see, the copyright stuff is still there). The wrapper is just collapsing, in part due to being in quirks mode.

Comment: Thank you-- that appears to have been the issue. IE drives me completely crazy and because of the way Wordpress includes files, I didn't realize this comment would end up at the very top of the HTML (or that it would create so much chaos for IE). Oh, to be able to go back in time and find the original IE developers and help them "get it right" the first time... :-) Thanks again.

Comment: @Eric - Since you're cleaning it up anyway, it might be worth using the HTML5 doctype, which forces all browsers (yes, even old ones like IE6/7) into the best standards mode that they have. Doing that, and having a good enough grasp on how things like `float` work can save a ton of headache when dealing with the old versions of IE. (Also, don't forget to accept answers.)